# Wordpress Automatic Update Plugin / Software

Tags: wordpress

Does someone know a software or plugin, except managewp, to update a bunch of blogs + plugins, which is also working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the [blog network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) feature enabled in WordPress, you should be able to update all blogs at once after updating the WordPress core files.  Once the sites are updated, you can update all plugins at once from the network plugin admin section.